# Is it possible deploy multiple container on single host with different sub domain and same listening port(80)?

Tags: docker, dns, docker-compose, azure-container-service

I have deployed 20 ASP.Net containers on Single Windows Server 2016. Here I have point containers with different ports in Same IP working fine. I need to expose on port 80 all the sites in containers to separate subdomains (eg: site1.serveraction.com, site2.serveraction.com)

But only one container working another one is going down.

Here my Docker compose file:

version: '3'
services:
 site1:
  image: "raj/con:site1"
  environment:
   - HOST_NAME=13.92.51.1XX
   - VIRTUAL_HOST=site1.serveractions.com
  ports:
   - "80:80"

version: '3'
services:
 site2:
  image: "raj/con:site2"
  environment:
   - HOST_NAME=13.92.51.1XX
   - VIRTUAL_HOST=site2.serveractions.com
  ports:
   - "80:80"

Comment: If you want to route traffic based on hostname, you will need a reverse proxy (for example apache, nginx, haproxy...)  in front of your servers, either running on host or in separate container.

Answer (score 0):

It is working as expected. One host port(80 in this case) can only be used by one container because there is only one port 80. The solution in your case would be to map different ports of the host to port 80 in your containers, i.e.

For container 1 --> Use port say 72801 to port 80, i.e. -p 72801:80

For container 2 --> Use port say 72802 to port 80, i.e. -p 72802:80

.

.

For container 20 --> Use port 72820 to port 80, i.e -p 72820:80

Now any service accessing container 1 has to go (address):72801 which would be forwarded to container 1's port 80, this would make sure you don't have any code related changes but the way(or ports) for accessing container's service will change.

Comment: Thanks, I have another question Is it possible map DNS  as like IIS with same port(80) for different domain in Docker ?

Comment: DNS doesn't get mapped to any ports.. In your scenario, you want site1.serveraction.com to go to container 1 and site2.serveraction.com to go to container 2 I believe.. so all you got to do is access container 1 now from site1.serveraction.com:72801 and access container 2 from site2.serveraction.com:72802 etc.